# xhtml file in a subfolder doesn't run

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have a xhtml file in a subfolder "WebContent/ems/about/about.xhtml" and when I run the file on the server I get the error java.io.FileNotFoundException.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:369)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._getLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:172)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.access$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:256)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:366)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

Here is my folder's hierarchy:

[image]

The files which are in WebContent/ems/* run properly.

Comment: Are you sure it is deployed?

Comment: Yes. The others xhml files from WebContent/ems run.

Comment: Are you sure the **others** are deployed. The Ones that don't work